# Google Calendar API returns invalid date time for correctly formatted dates? [PHP]

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

Recently I've started getting errors, with code 400, that I'm using invalid start time.

```
Google_Service_Exception
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid start time."
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid start time."
 }
}
```

Dates are formatted with format:
`Y-m-d\TH:i:sP`
and these are start and end properties in API call:

```
start: {
    dateTime: 2022-01-17T08:30:00+01:00, 
    timeZone: Europe/Amsterdam
},
end: {
    dateTime: 2022-01-17T16:30:00+01:00, 
    timeZone: Europe/Amsterdam
}
```

I've tried using Zulu time format, but that wouldn't take time zone in account even though it's passed.
Any idea what to do to resolve this error?

Comment: The timezone inserted is normally the time zone of the calendar itself.   Check the timezone of the calendar and then adjust the time accordingly.

Comment: Kindly include your code in your post above.